# What is the difference between Reactive-Extensions/RxJS and ReactiveX/rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

I am a bit confused. What is the difference between these libraries?


https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

What is the differance between [rx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx), [@reactivex/rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reactivex/rxjs) [rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) on npm.

If you search npm there are multiple libraries for rxjs which one is the official?

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=rx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RxJS 4 is hosted on: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

RxJS 5 (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) replaces RxJS 4 and is relatively compatible with RxJS 4. [README.md on gtihub says](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#rxjs-5-release-candidate):

> Reactive Extensions Library for JavaScript. This is a rewrite of Reactive-Extensions/RxJS and is intended to supersede it once this is ready.

RxJS 5 is completely written in TypeScript and compiled to both as ES6 and ES5 (as a bundle in UMD format).

There's also RxJS 6 currently in development.

Also, RxJS 4 is now called `rx` and npm while RxJS 5 is `rxjs` now. The scoped one `@reactivex/rxjs` is probably just an older npm package (they both come from the same repo).

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: Note that they also changed some of the API in RxJS 5, so code written for RxJS 4 won't work with RxJS 5 without a migration effort.